# (Java) How to return objects from a list as a string or array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, tostring

**EDIT: I have uploaded both full class files and a tester file to dropbox in case you want to try it out yourselves:** https://www.dropbox.com/sh/03qsecq3bd55w78/AAA_PT_BczNGl7cTZO_Zf_qUa?dl=0

First off, sorry if this is a very simple question - I've only just started working with java and I don't have a lot of programming experience at all.

So I have two classes: Posada and Camino. Posada contains a list of Camino objects. I need to override Posada's toString method so that it returns a string containing all of the toString methods of the Camino objects its list contains, like so:

Posada:

```
public class Posada {

    /*other attributes*/
    private List<Camino> listCaminos;   

    /*Getters*/
    public List<Camino> getLisaCaminos() {
        return listCaminos;
    }

    /*Builder*/
    public Posada(String nombre, int engRecuperada) {
        /*Other attributes*/
        this.listaCaminos = new ArrayList<Camino>();
    }

    /*Methods*/
    public String getStringToReturn(){
        String[] arrayCaminos = listCaminos.toArray(new
        String[listCaminos.size()]);

        String string = "";
        string += /*Some other attributes that go before the Camino objects
        and work fine*/;

        for(int i = 0; i < listCaminos.size(); i++) {
            string += ", " + arrayCaminos[i];
        }

        return string;
    }

    /*toString*/
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getStringToReturn(); //failure
    }

}
```

Camino

```
public class Camino {

    /*Attributes*/
    private Posada origin;
    private Posada destination;
    private int cost;

    private static int costTotal;

    /*Contructor*/
    public Camino(Posada origin, Posada destination, int cost){
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.cost = cost;
        Camino.costTotal = Camino.costTotal + cost;

    }

    /*Getters*/
    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public Posada getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public Posada getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    /*Methods. Irrelevant*/


    /*toString*/
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + getOrigin() + "--" + getCost() + "-->" +
        getDestination()+ ")";
    }

}
```

So the expected result when printing Posada should be something like "Other_attributes, (originCamino1--costCamino1-->destinationCamino1), (originCamino2--costCamino2-->destinationCamino2), (..), (originCaminoN--costCaminoN-->destinationCaminoN)", N being the total number of Camino objects in the list. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
at apartado1.Posada.getStringToReturn(Posada.java:106)
at apartado1.Posada.toString(Posada.java:121)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
```

I know it's got to be something really easy to fix, but I've been looking around and it just won't work no matter what I do. I've tried using toString() and toArray(), but I get the same results. Here's hoping you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How could Java store instances of Camino into an array of Strings? Why transform a list to an array in the first place: you can iterate on a list directly.

Answer (score 1):

`listCaminos.toArray()` must return an array of `Camino`. You can't pass in `String[]`.

Change the first line of `Camino.getStringToReturn()` to

```
Camino[] arrayCaminos = listCaminos.toArray(new Camino[listCaminos.size()]);
```

Should work fine now.

**EDIT:** Looking at your code again, I don't understand why you're using an array in the first place. Why not iterate over the list elements?

Comment: When I change that, I get the following error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at apartado1.Posada.getStringToReturn(Posada.java:106)
 at apartado1.Posada.toString(Posada.java:120)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
 at apartado1.Camino.toString(Camino.java:68)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
 at apartado1.Posada.getStringToReturn(Posada.java:111)
 at apartado1.Posada.toString(Posada.java:120)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)

Comment: @AlexQ. Looks like `Camino` is referencing its parent `Posada` in either `origin` or `destination`, resulting in an infinite recursion, since the `toString` methods depend on each other. You'll need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Ah... I see now! So that's what it meant! I'll have to figure out how to do this without making an infinite loop then. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why does the default implementation of ArrayList not work ? This this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return listCaminos.toString();
}
```

Comment: When I change that, I get the following error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.iterator(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
 at apartado1.Posada.toString(Posada.java:121)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
 at apartado1.Camino.toString(Camino.java:68)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)

Comment: Still the StackOverFlow Error ? The cause may be because you invoke getOrigin() in the Camino toString Method. That causes the Posada toString to be invoked and so on..  try getOrigin().hashcode() or sth to break the cycle

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this with Java 8:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Other_attributes, " +
        listCaminos.stream()
            .map(Camino::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

There is no need to convert the list to an array before iterating it, and with Java 8 streams there is no need to even iterate the list to create a comma-delimited string of the Camino objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either what Matthias suggested, or if you want a customized output, you could loop through each of the elements and concatenate their toString outputs.

Something like this:

```
public String toString(){
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for (Camino camino : listCaminos) {
         builder.append(camino.toString()).append(",");
     }
     return builder.toString();
}
```

You can strip off the extra "," at the end.

Comment: When I change that, I get teh following error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at apartado1.Camino.toString(Camino.java:68)
 at apartado1.Posada.toString(Posada.java:123)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
 at apartado1.Camino.toString(Camino.java:68)
 at apartado1.Posada.toString(Posada.java:123)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)

Comment: That is because you seem to have a cyclic dependency, and toString method of each class is calling the toString method of the other class. Please correct the code accordingly

Answer (score -1):

I'd rather use a foreach loop inside toString, like:

```
public String toString()
{
     String ret = "";
     for (Camino camino : listCaminos)
     {
         ret += camino.toString() + "\n";
     }
     return ret;
}
```

Instead of using \n (as new line), you can use comma as your example.
Evenmore, it could be improved using StringBuilder if performance improvements are necessary.